# Why don't we have timeout for review audit questions?

Tags: discussion, review, stack-exchange, review-audits

Why don't we have timeout for review audits?

Consider the following scenario:

1. User A access the review queue.
2. He/she chooses one question, which happens to be a review audit.
3. User A won't take any actions.
4. User B access the review queue also.
5. User B comments on the low quality posts.
6. User A viewing the content can see the comment that user B made, and user A can simply bypass the review audits.

Comment: AFAIK same audit doesn't come to two users.

Comment: @hims056 it comes i personally checked it.i dont know how to reproduce the scenario,unless the reviewer a/b presses the skip/i am done button the questions still on review queue ,if possible check parallely with friend

Comment: The scenario you describe sounds plausible, but can it really happen often enough to justify developer time? I don't think so...

Comment: If someone's loading up a post and not immediately taking the wrong action, they're probably not the kind of badge-seeking robo-reviewer the audit system is trying to weed out. So mission accomplished.